# How to save classification_report results in loop for each classifier in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to train models with different classifiers. and want to save each classifiers classification report in csv file to get score values of classes.But when am trying to do this following error came up.
I will really appreciate if some one can help me to resolve this issue, i can do testing individually with each classifiers and save to file. but it will increase my code that i really don't want.

```
raise ValueError("Mix type of y not allowed, got types %s" % ys_types)
ValueError: Mix type of y not allowed, got types {'multiclass', 'continuous- 
multioutput'}

**this is the code am trying with:**
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, log_loss
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier, 
GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
```

### import pandas as pd

,Phone,Base_ID,Cell_ID,ULTraffic,TCPSYNAtteDelay,date

1,13548599180,54,251,469,28,20160718034300.0
2,13548599180,1,46,1273,31,20160725023800.0
3,13548599180,54,251,1273,25,20160714012400.0
4,13548599180,54,251,1273,31,20160714085200.0
5,13548599180,54,251,1273,31,20160718034200.0
6,13548599180,54,251,1273,25,20160713082200.0
7,13548599180,54,251,2373,33,20160713091800.0
8,13548599180,54,251,2373,33,20160713091800.0
9,13548599180,54,251,639,31,20160714015300.0
10,13548599180,92,278,690,28,20160704010900.0
11,13548599180,92,278,693,28,20160704010900.0
12,13548599180,92,278,689,31,20160704010900.0
13,13548599180,92,278,1060,25,20160704010900.0
14,13548599180,54,251,1339,29,20160713091500.0
15,13548599180,54,251,1202,29,20160713091500.0
16,13548599180,54,251,975,26,20160713091500.0
17,13548599180,54,251,745,29,20160714015300.0
18,13548599180,54,251,707,27,20160714015300.0

```
url = 'path\stackflow_sample.csv'
names = ['Phone','Base_ID', 'Cell_ID', 'ULTraffic', 
'TCPSYNAtteDelay','date']

data = pd.read_csv(url, names=names,low_memory=False)
a=data.loc[:,('Phone','Base_ID', 'Cell_ID', 'ULTraffic',         
'TCPSYNAtteDelay','date')]
data_dia = a.Phone ; x_1 = a.drop('Phone',axis = 1 )
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_1, data_dia, 
test_size=0.3, random_state=42)



classifiers = [
KNeighborsClassifier(3)]
DecisionTreeClassifier()
RandomForestClassifier(),
AdaBoostClassifier(),
GradientBoostingClassifier(),
GaussianNB(),
LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()]

# Logging for Visual Comparison
log_cols = ["Classifier", "Accuracy", "Log Loss"]
log = pd.DataFrame(columns=log_cols)

     for clf in classifiers:
         clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
         name = clf.__class__.__name__

        print("=" * 30)
        print(name)

        print('****Results****')
        train_predictions = clf.predict(x_test)
        acc = accuracy_score(y_test, train_predictions)
        print("Accuracy: {:.4%}".format(acc))

        train_predictions = clf.predict_proba(x_test)
        ll = log_loss(y_test, train_predictions)
        print("Log Loss: {}".format(ll))

        log_entry = pd.DataFrame([[name, acc * 100, ll]], columns=log_cols)
        log = log.append(log_entry)
        report = classification_report(y_test, train_predictions)
    print("log:",log)
    print("=" * 30)

**This is the function am using to save classification_report results of 
classifiers in other file func.py **


def classifaction_report_csv(report):
    report_data = []
    lines = report.split('\n')
    for line in lines[2:-3]:
        row = {}
        row_data = line.split('      ')
        row['class'] = row_data[0]
        row['precision'] = float(row_data[1])
        row['recall'] = float(row_data[2])
        row['f1_score'] = float(row_data[3])
        row['support'] = float(row_data[4])
        report_data.append(row)
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(report_data)
    dataframe.to_csv('classification_report.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Check your labels. Where is the traceback coming from?

Comment: okay am uploading the sample data and further code